# how can i get spesific words from an url in java

Tags: java, url

How can i get spesific words from an url in java. Like i want to take datas from class which calling like blablabla.
Here is my code.

```
    URL url = new URL("https://www.doviz.com/");
    URLConnection connect = url.openConnection();
    InputStream is = connect.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line = null;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please review the how to ask page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you can get better responses if you include more details, like "I want to look for x, and then do y. I tried going about it as per z, but it didn't work because v" I promise you you will get better responses if you can add these kinds of details

Comment: What do you mean? You mean you want to count occurrences of a specific word in a webpage?

Comment: @MarsAtomic Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) , this will allow you to get the content of a web page and **NOT** the HTML code. Let's say it will play the role of the browser, it will parse the HTML tags into a human readable text.

Once you will get the content of your page in a String, you can count the occurrences of your word using any algorithm of occurrences count.

Simple example to use it:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
/*   ........  */
String URL = "https://www.doviz.com/";       
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
String text = doc.body().text();
System.out.println(text);
```

**EDIT**

If you don't want to use a parser (as you mentioned in the comment that you don't want external libraries), you will get the whole HTML code of the page, that's how you can do it

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("https://www.doviz.com/");       

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        str = in.readLine().toString();
        System.out.println(str);
        /*str will get each time the new line, if you want to store the whole text in str 
           you can use concatenation (str+ = in.readLine().toString())*/
    }
    in.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: is there any other way to get content of a web page? Without using external libraries

Comment: no, in my knowledge you will always need a parser (like Jsoup), otherwise you will get the HTML tag  (actually the whole code of the page) with it and this may confuse you in the research of the specific word

Comment: @Yuaud if you don't mind getting the HTML code, read the edited part of my answer. and if my answer helped you don't hesitate to accept it by clicking on the check mar on the left. thanks and good luck with your project :))